# Custom message filter for logstash

Tags: logstash-configuration

Log:

```
20160927-210452.110|I|cpeg-001.anc.com|test_app-1.5-0||~|f324dfsdf23sd23||org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean:777|Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Filter

```
filter {
  grok{
     match => [ "message", "(?<date_time>[0-9.-]+)(?<delimiter>[|])%{WORD:method}(?<delimiter>[|])%{USERNAME:host_name}(?<delimiter>[|])%{USERNAME:app_name_version}(?<delimiter>[|~]+)%{USERNAME:session}(?<delimiter>[|]+)(?<class_name>.+)(?<delimiter>[|])(?<log_message>.+)" ]

     remove_field => [ "delimiter" ]
   }
}
```

Is there any way to skip '|' other than 'remove_field' ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not hardcode the `|` inside your grok pattern? You can escape it using `\|`

**Pattern:**

```
 (?<date_time>[0-9.-]+)\|%{WORD:method}\|%{USERNAME:host_name}\|%{USERNAME:app_name_version}\|\|\~\|%{USERNAME:session}\|\|%{DATA:classname}\|%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}
```

**Filter:**

```
grok{
    match => [ "message", "(?<date_time>[0-9.-]+)\|%{WORD:method}\|%{USERNAME:host_name}\|%{USERNAME:app_name_version}\|\|\~\|%{USERNAME:session}\|\|%{DATA:classname}\|%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" ]
}
```

It works. You can test this using the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks
I just created custom patten

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I just created custom patten in ./custom_patterns/my_pattern:

```
CUST_DATETIME [0-9.-]+
SEPARATOR \|
MULTI_SEPARATOR \|\|\~\|
```

Updated the same in filter-match:

```
filter {
  grok{
    patterns_dir => "./custom_patterns"

    match => [ "message", "%{CUST_DATETIME:orb_date}%{SEPARATOR}%{WORD:method}%{SEPARATOR}%{USERNAME:host_name}%{SEPARATOR}%{USERNAME:app_name_version}%{MULTI_SEPARATOR}%{USERNAME:session}%{SEPARATOR}%{DATA:class_name}%{SEPARATOR}%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}" ]

   }
}
```